# angularjs translation with parameter which is also translated

Tags: angularjs, translation

how can I translate expression:

```
     <div translation = "download" translate-values = "{{'msg': 'file.pdf'}}">
     </ Div>
     <div translation = "download" translate-values = "{{'msg': 'file.pic'}}">
     </ Div>
```

when in file en.json

```
...{
download : "Download {{ msg | translation}}"
   file: {
     pdf: "pdf file"
         pic: "pictures"
     }
   }
```

I want to have results, for example:
english
"Download pdf file" and "Download pictures"
and in polish
"Sciagnij pik pdf" and "Sciagnij obrazki"

Answer (score 0):

ok I already know ... I made a mistake on:

```
 <div translation = "download" translate-values = "{{'msg': 'file.pdf'}}"></div>
```

should:

```
 <div translation = "download" translate-values = "{'msg': 'file.pdf'}"></div>
```